# How to fix "Unable to find the controller for path /login_check"?

Tags: symfony

I'm creating an api with symfony2, I created the 'public part' and now I want to allow access at a part of admin side. So in api side users have to identify. 
The login form is displayed correctly, but when I'm trying to connect this error is returned :

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/api/admin/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
```

**my firewall in security.yml**

```
firewalls
    api:
        pattern: ^/api/admin
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /api/admin/login.json
            check_path: /api/admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /api/admin/list/questionnaires.json
        context: my_context
        anonymous: true
```

**in routing.yml**

```
api_login_check:
    pattern:   /api/admin/login_check
```

the router:debug show me

```
api_login_check                     ANY      ANY    ANY  /api/admin/login_check
api_admin_get_login                 GET      ANY    ANY  /api/admin/login.{_format}
api_admin_get_list_questionnaires   GET      ANY    ANY  /api/admin/list/questionnaires.{_format}
```

the two last routes are generated by fosrestbundle.

do you know where I'm wrong ? what's happens ?  and how to resolve ?

thanks

Comment: Your title has one error message, your question has another.  Which one are you getting?  Typically, a SecurityBundle request listener will process login_check requests.  It would seem that it's not configured correctly.

Comment: this in the message of course, the title is a kind of general case, I think /api/admin is not a pertinent information in a title but more imporant in the message.That's why I choose to do this.What do you think about that? Next time I will not do like that.I have some others firewalls for different connexion forms, one is almost the same as this one but is used for the normal website part (not in api) and all are working fine.However I forgot to say something, I'm getting the content of these pages with file_get_contents() and it seems that login_check is waiting for post request. I gonna try

Comment: Yep.  The login_check listener will only be kicked off on post.  I'm thinking you might be trying to mix an api authentication system with a form based system.  As far as error messages go, I can't tell you how many threads I have seen where the poster either edits the error message or posts one problem with an error message from another.  I find it best to be sure and seldom rely on "of course".